# stop() implementation in guava's AbstractService class

Tags: guava

I was trying to understand how guava's AbstractService has been implemented. In the interface Service the various state transitions have been mentioned. One such transition is from STOPPING -> TERMINATED when the call to stop() is successful.

Now when I am seeing how AbstractService's stop() has been implemented, I found that on case STOPPING, they fall through and don't change the state to TERMINATED.

I may be wrong, I am just trying to learn and understand how it works.

The code for AbstractService class is given here. http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractService.java?r=8d5659ad0e137d3a594014793264292a75b48bb9

Search for stop() on the page to see its implementation

Comment: Actually I find that this case will never arise. Can someone please confirm I am thinking correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `stop()` in the `RUNNING` state, the state is changed to `STOPPING` and the `doStop()` method gets called. Calling `stop()` again after that shouldn't do anything. The `doStop()` implementation should call `notifyStopped()` which changes the state from `STOPPING` to `TERMINATED`.